# ElasticSearch - search statistic - like google analytics

Tags: search, google-analytics, elasticsearch, kibana

I am looking into using ElasticSearch as a search engine for one of the projects I am working on.
There is still one thing which I need to find an answer for, and I hope someone inhere can help.

The customer want to be able to see some search statistic, like google analytics. Most searched words, new search words and so on. 
Is there a way to easily setup this type of search statistic. My idea is something like ElasticSearch stores search history, about the search request made to the REST API. Then my customer can use Kibana or some other visual tool to monitor the search history of ElasticSearch.

Hope someone can help me with an answer for this.

Regards
Jacob

Answer (score 0):

You could adjust the `slow log` to a time which it will capture all requests, however this will then produce large log files which will require maintenance. You could write an application which handles all of your ES requests, takes the search phrase and indexes this in a separate index i.e. your search history index and then deals with the actual request as normal, returning the response to the user.

Comment: Hello Nate. Thank you for your input. I see your point, I could index search information from the application making the search, but I was hoping that ElasticSearch would have some kind of standard way of providing search analytics. Regards Jacob

Comment: Jacob, as far as I am aware, logging the request via the `slowlog` is the only was. Other than the method I stated above. It is good practice to have a layer of abstraction between user and data store. Have a search and see if anyone has written a plugin since I last looked myself or came up with another solution. Nate